# Users Unable to Access Home Page: This Site Has Not Been Shared with You

Tags: 2013, permissions, groups, homepage

I am having issues getting users to access the homepage for our work Sharepoint Website. Any individual who tries to access it gets the message "This Site Has Not Been Shared with You." However, they can access any of the other pages on the site if they input the link for it.

We have tried every conceivable way of changing permissions for our users so that they can view this page. The only way anyone can view this page is if they are made a Site Collection Administrator. Since our work has over 2000 people, it's not feasible to make everyone a Collection Administrator.

We did notice, that the visitor groups under which the vast majority of our users belong, do have Limited Access. We think that might be the cause of the problem, but we are unable to remove this, it is grayed out in the Permissions Tab.

If anyone has any insight on how to fix this, it would be much appreciated. Trying to get my boss off my back :)

Answer (score 0):

Good day!

You don't want to be assigning many people site collection admin. This should just be limited to a handful of admins at best.

Every SharePoint site has three standard permissions groups created with it. They are...

- Owners Group: Has almost all the same powers as a site collection admin
- Members Group: Can edit content, cannot edit structure (cannot add / edit/ delete columns in lists/libraries for example)
- Visitor Group: Has read access only, can view but cannot edit anything.

If this is an Intranet like page were all employees should see it but not edit it, than this should be handled via the visitors group. You can either add individual names in the visitors group or add the term "Everyone" which gives all authenticated users view access to the page. These groups I mentioned can be accessed via Site Settings - Site Permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for that Access denied is either that the default page is not published or that the permissions on the pages library have been broken. You have checked both, right?